# Open a browser in Electron

Tags: reactjs, electron

Currently, when I click on the link in a React component, it opens the URL inside the Electron app which I don't want. I tried using used target _blank to open a browser and it didn't work. How do I open a browser from an Electron app when I click the link?

Here are what I have done:

From a React Component

```
<div className="form-group">
  <label htmlFor="uname1">Open Google from <a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">here</a>)</label>
</div>
```

The main.js in of the Electron

```
const {app, BrowserWindow,Menu, shell} = require('electron')
const isDev = require('electron-is-dev')

process.env.NODE_ENV = "development"

const isMac = process.platform === "darwin" ? true : false

let mainWindow

function createMainWindow (){
     mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width:1024,
        height:768,
        show: false,
        backgroundColor:"#263238"
       
    })

    mainWindow.loadURL(isDev ? 'http://localhost:3000' : `file://${path.join(__dirname, '../build/index.html')}`)

    mainWindow.once('ready-to-show', () => {
        mainWindow.show();
        mainWindow.focus();
      });
}


document.body.addEventListener('click', event => {
    if (event.target.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'a' && event.target.protocol != 'file:') {
      event.preventDefault();
      shell.openExternal(event.target.href);
    }
  });
```

Many thanks in advance and greatly appreciate any helps. Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this listener:

```
mainWindow.webContents.on('new-window', function(event, url){    
    event.preventDefault();  
    electron.shell.openExternal(url);
}
```